# In Puppet, on which node should I declare the puppetlabs-aws classes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet, puppetlabs-aws

If I want to use the [puppetlabs-aws](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-aws) module to create Amazon AWS instances, on which node in my puppet hierarchy should I declare those classes? Obviously I can't declare them on the nodes that I'm about to create, so where, then? When and how does the manifest get applied?

Comment: You would run the infrastructure provisioning from a bootstrap (probably master) and the software provisioning on the node. But really you should do the infra prov with Terraform instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter where the manifest runs. You could `puppet apply` the manifests in your local dev environment as a quick way to get started. In a production environment, you might alternatively have a dedicated node that is classified as your "provisioner" where you choose to run manifests from. There's nothing preventing you from classifying your existing Puppet Master as the "provisioner" either.